# In PureScript, how does List differ from Array?

Tags: purescript

In PureScript, how does `List` differ from `Array`?

What are the reasons to use one over the other?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The representation for `Array` is a JavaScript array, whereas `List` is implemented as a cons (linked) list.

`List`s have better performance characteristics when being built up item-by-item, or iterated over by taking an item from front each time - basically `List` has `O(1)` `cons` and `uncons`, vs `O(n)` for `Array`.

Take a look at the documentation for [`Array`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-arrays/4.1.1/docs/Data.Array) and [`List`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-lists/4.0.1/docs/Data.List) on Pursuit for more information about the running time of various operations.

Comment: It is worth noting that the List notation in Purescript (for example `[1,2,3]`) produces an `Array` of the given type and not a `List`.

Comment: To add further, ```1 : 2 : 3 : Nil``` will give you the required ```List``` of elements ```[1,2,3]```

Comment: Also, `import Data.List (range)` then `range 1 3` also produces `(1 : 2 : 3 : Nil)`, which is a list, and not an array.